# Purpose of ContextResolver in JAX-RS

Tags: java, jax-rs

I want to understand the purpose of context resolver in JAX-RS. In what scenarios I should implement context resolver? Can someone elaborate with some example?

I referrred JAX-RS 2.0 spec and found below paragraph:

> Context providers supply context to resource classes and other providers. A context provider class implements
>       the ContextResolver interface and may be annotated with @Provider for automatic discovery.
>       E.g., an application wishing to provide a customized JAXBContext to the default JAXB entity
>       providers would supply a class implementing ContextResolver.

I couldn't understand where and when to use.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the ContextResolver to translate camel casing to underscores (see example below), so basically you can do configuration (just like the documentations states).

```
package com.example;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ContextResolver;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class ObjectMapperContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public ObjectMapperContextResolver() {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(
                PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES
        );
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what is purpose of changing camel casing to underscore? and on what it will change?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you may have special requirements for your json binding (camel case handling, null value handling, private field handling, ...). You can provide a ContextResolver (annotate your ContextResolver implementation with Provider) to let CDI pick up and use that resolver for your json bindings.